# How to find the L3 cache index and NUMA node index for the current hardware thread

Tags: c++, c, x86, numa, cpuid

I'm building a topological tree of sockets, NUMA nodes, caches, cores, and threads for any Intel or AMD system in C.

Building this hierarchy, I want to ensure hardware threads are grouped together appropriately so it's clear who precisely shares what. I've found that I can set a thread's affinity and then use the `cpuid` instruction to get a lot of the info I want, but not all.

If a package/socket has multiple NUMA nodes, how do I get an index of the NUMA node for the current hardware thread? If the NUMA node has multiple L3 caches, how do I get the index?

[AMD](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/25481.pdf) has something for NUMA node ID in `Fn8000_001E_ECX`, but I can't find anything comparable for [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.html). And nothing re: L3 index for either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If a package/socket has multiple NUMA nodes, how do I get an index of the NUMA node for the current hardware thread?

You get this information from ACPI.

Specifically, there's a "System Resource Affinity Table" (SRAT) that contains a list of structures describing which NUMA domain different things (CPUs, memory areas, ...) are in at boot time. For 80x86; you'd parse this list looking for both "Processor Local APIC/SAPIC Affinity Structures" and "Processor Local x2APIC Affinity Structures".

For hot-plug CPUs the table isn't enough (the SRAT won't change when a CPU is inserted or removed after boot), so you might also need to use an ACPI machine language interpreter to execute `_PXM` objects to obtain current NUMA information. Computers that support hot-plug CPUs is very rare though.

Note that in ACPI "NUMA domain numbers" are excessively large (32 bits) and not guaranteed to be contiguous (e.g. in theory you could have 2 NUMA nodes with the NUMA domain numbers 0x12345678 and 0x9ABCDEF0); which means that you can't use them for array indexes (e.g. if you want to do something like "`NUMA_stats[domain].CPU_count++;`" it won't be fun). There is also no standard value reserved for "unknown NUMA domain", which is inconvenient for code that determines topology (e.g. you'd need a separate "did/didn't find a valid NUMA domain" flag to keep track).

Comment: So for user-space, you'll have to ask the OS somehow, at least for access to that ACPI data.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes. Ideally the OS would obtain all of the topology info (and sanity check it, and correct any errata), and provide a nice portable API with complete information (e.g. like `SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION` in Windows but with more info), and user-space wouldn't ever want to use `CPUID` or ACPI (unnecessary, non-portable, unchecked, uncorrected). I'd even suggest that, in a perfect world, user-space would be banned from using `CPUID` (too easy for malware to detect security vulnerabilities in CPU). Someone needs to write the OS though.. ;)

Comment: Neat idea, but there are legit performance reasons for wanting to know the CPU model number, e.g. to choose not to use `pshufb`-based functions on CPUs that have it but where it's slow (K8, Core 2 Conroe, what x264 calls "SlowShuffle" as a CPU feature).  Or more generally for `gcc -march=native` setting tuning options.

Comment: If you make this hypothetical OS use HW virt to trap every CPUID execution, you can sanitize it some, but I think you'd be hard pressed to give user-space as much info as it needs for every existing program to do all the legit things some user processes currently do, without making it pretty easy to fingerprint a CPU model even based on available features and maybe a microbenchmark or two.  Hiding microcode revision could be a thing, though, for processes without some system-info capability / privilege.

Comment: @PeterCordes: There's legitimate reasons for an OS to provide (e.g.) a "pshufb is fast/slow" flag or a "micro-arch number" (and still not allow access to the exact stepping/sub-stepping information or micro-code update version number or "software visible work-arounds" flags). There's also plenty of cases where CPUID provides wrong information, "technically correct but bad" info (e.g. that a known buggy feature is supported), doesn't provide information at all, or where the same information is provided in one of many different ways.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Note that when I said "Someone needs to write the OS" I meant it more like "the original asker might be writing an OS (and might not be able to rely on any kind of topology API provided by an existing OS)".

Comment: Yeah, I'm stuck firmly in user space. It seems like this kind of topological information would be of interest to a lot of performance-sensitive concurrent applications, but they may make assumptions about the homogeneity of the architecture that tend to hold true in most commercial hardware.